# How does Phantom DSL for Cassandra actually connect?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'd like to use the [Phantom DSL](https://github.com/websudos/phantom) for Cassandra from Scala. I've noted that it uses the Datastax Java driver underneath, but I don't see anything in the documentation about how to actually connect or configure a connection. The included tests use an embedded Cassandra, so that doesn't help. Are there any detailed examples or tutorials for this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run operations with Phantom "tables" you need to have implicit Session object in scope. One way to achieve that is CassandraConnector, and you can build connectors using **ContactPoint**. For instance you can use [**this example**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/db/TestDatabase.scala#L36).

Or you can build your own way of initializing implicit Session.

**Update**

Additionally you can read about connectors in more depth on [**this blog post**](http://outworkers.com/blog/post/phantom-tips-3-understanding-phantom-connectors).

Comment: Also you can take a look at this example: https://github.com/websudos/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-example/src/main/scala/com/websudos/phantom/example/basics/DBConnector.scala

Comment: Is this Simple Connector the best way to go for production?

Comment: @ThiagoPereira You can easily override the way clusters are built to add logging information and so forth. Depending on how many Cassandra nodes you are using the connector is a good fit.